# Proof by induction without a closed form

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers, induction, prime-factorization

I need to do a proof by induction without the use of a closed form (I do know it's possible to find one, but we aren't supposed to do it that way).

Here's the prompt:

Let $p_1, p_2, p_3, \ldots, p_m$ be distinct primes. 
Let $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_m$ be positive integers. 
Suppose the following

\begin{equation}
N = (p_{1})^{a_{1}} \cdot (p_{2})^{a_{2}} \cdot (p_{3})^{a_{3}} \cdot \ldots \cdot (p_{m})^{a_{m}} 
\end{equation}

How many divisors does $N$ have?

I already figured out that the number of divisors of N is:

$Divisors\hspace{.2cm} of\hspace{.2cm} N = (a_{1} + 1) \cdot (a_{2} + 1) \cdot (a_{3} + 1) \cdot \ldots \cdot (a_{m} + 1) $

I asked my professor how to do an induction proof with only this, and he said:

"To interpret this as an induction proof, do induction on m. So, assuming that some number $N$ has m prime factors, consider a number $N'$ that has $m+1$ prime factors. Show that if N has $(a_1 + 1)\cdot(a_2+1)\cdot(a_3+1)\cdot \ldots \cdot(a_m+1)$ total factors, then $N'$ has $(a_1 + 1)\cdot(a_2+1)\cdot(a_3+1)\cdot \ldots \cdot(a_m+1)\cdot(a_{m+1} + 1)$ total factors."

I am still struggling to understand how to do this. Of course you could say, let:

$N = p_{1}^{a_{1}}p_{2}^{a_{2}}$

and let :

$N' = p_{1}^{a_{1}}p_{2}^{a_{2}}p_{3}^{a_{3}}$

and then :

$N' = N \cdot p_{3}^{a_{3}}$

but I really don't understand how to proceed from there in order to reach any sort of conclusion.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For each factor in $N'$, it can choose to match up with one $p_{m+1}^t$ where $t \in \{0,1,2,...,a_{m+1}\}$, so that gives us $(a_{m+1}+1)\cdot$(number of factors in $N$).

Comment: @LazyLee Hi , yes thank you for responding:) I understand that, but I don't understand what that proves... like what conclusions can be drawn from that that prove how many factors are in N'